# can you have an array with no element at index 0

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing

Im wondering if it is possible to insert an element at index 1 but not index 0 in swift like this:

```
            var array = [String]()

            array.insert("cow", atIndex: 1)
```

but every time I try I get the old fatal error: Array index out of range error message.

Is there anyway around this problem? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: My first response is that you should rethink your architecture. I could be wrong, but the fact that you think you need to do this could be a Bad Smell. Why would you need to do such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make it an array of optionals and initialize the number of elements you want first, you can get close.

```
var array = [String?]()
for i in 0...5 {
    array.append(nil)
}

array.insert("cow", atIndex: 1)
```

Comment: Damn that's a good idea. I'd never thought of this one! Thanks!

Comment: perhaps you could even implement this to a function and add it as an extension? Or that wouldn't be possible?

Comment: For any case where I might want to do this, I'd probably use a dictionary instead.  It was just an interesting problem.  :)

Comment: Instead of initializing with a loop, use `var array = [String?](count: 6, repeatedValue: nil)` to initialize the array.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want the index to be specific, rather than just the next available position in the array, you should use a dictionary with Int keys.

```
var dict = [Int:String]()
dict[1] = "Cow"
dict[5] = "Chicken"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom list. You will need to add some checking to make sure items aren't null or out of index, etc.

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new CustomList<string>();
    list.Add("Chicken");
    list.Add("Bear");

    list[1] = "Cow";

    list[1].Dump(); //output Cow
}

public class CustomList<T>
{
    IList<T> list = new List<T>();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        list.Add(item);
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
       get
       {
           return list[index - 1];
       }
       set
       {
            list[index - 1] = value;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Literally you can't.

An item can be inserted up to the maximum index `index(max) = array.count`, in case of an empty array at index 0.